# how i can define a function in python 3

Tags: python-3.x

```
def paperwork(n, m):
    c=n*m
        if n < 0 or m<0:
            c=0
    return c
```

error=
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in 
    from solution import *
  File "/home/codewarrior/solution.py", line 3
    if n < 0:
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: your indentation is incorrect.

Comment: You need to unindent line 3. Python syntax cares about indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The python interpreter cares about indentation. Your code as above fails because the interpreter doesn't know how to parse line 3, since it has one more indentation than expected.

```
def paperwork(n, m):
    c=n*m
        if n < 0 or m<0:
            c=0
    return c
```

If you unindent the 3rd and 4th lines, then the code will work:

```
def paperwork(n, m):
    c=n*m
    if n < 0 or m<0:
        c=0
    return c
```

For a more in depth explanation of indentation in python syntax the following page is useful:

[Indentation in python](https://www.w3schools.in/python-tutorial/concept-of-indentation-in-python/)